# Sails-permissions test, create records using bluebird

Tags: sails.js, waterline, bluebird

So i'm playing around with sails-permissions. I'm trying to create a simple system where users can login, create companies, then other people can join those companies and see everyone else in the company.

I want to create some users in my bootstrap file before all my test run. That way all my test can utilize those users.

This [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjdr4.jpg) basically shows it all (link because It's huge). I create 2 companies, and 10 users. This part works fine, However, when sails-permissions attempts to link roles to the newly created users it gets all confused and tries to create a million links to the last user that was created.

Company.js

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      minLength: 3,
      maxLength: 255,
      unique: true,
      index: true
    }
  }
}
```

User.js

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var _super = require('sails-permissions/api/models/User');

_.merge(exports, _super);
_.merge(exports, {
  attributes: {
    // Extend with custom logic here by adding additional fields, methods, etc.
    company: {
      model: 'Company'
    }
  }
});
```

Bootstrap file:

```
/**
 * Test starter - with this version of sails.js we can only start one sails server,
 * to solve this problem we use only one before All and after All to start and
 * stop the server
 */
var Sails = require('sails');
var ConfigOverrides = require('../config/env/testing');
var Promise = require('bluebird');

var sails;

before(function (done) {

  this.timeout(100000);

  Sails.lift(ConfigOverrides, function (err, server) {

    sails = server;

    if (err) {
      return done(err);
    }

    // Companies
    var company1 = {name: 'Company 1'};
    var company2 = {name: 'Company 2'};

    // Users
    var company1Owner = {username: 'Company 1 owner', email: 'admin@company1.com', password: 'password'};
    var company2Owner = {username: 'Company 2 owner', email: 'admin@company2.com', password: 'password'};

    var company1Employee1 = {username: 'company1 Employee 1', email: '1@company1.com', password: 'password'};
    var company1Employee2 = {username: 'company1 Employee 2', email: '2@company1.com', password: 'password'};
    var company1Employee3 = {username: 'company1 Employee 3', email: '3@company1.com', password: 'password'};

    var company2Employee1 = {username: 'company2 Employee 1', email: '1@company2.com', password: 'password'};
    var company2Employee2 = {username: 'company2 Employee 2', email: '2@company2.com', password: 'password'};
    var company2Employee3 = {username: 'company2 Employee 3', email: '3@company2.com', password: 'password'};
    var company2Employee4 = {username: 'company2 Employee 4', email: '4@company2.com', password: 'password'};

    var registered = {username: 'registered', email: 'registered@foobar.com', password: 'password'};

    Promise.all([
      Company.create(company1),
      Company.create(company2)
    ])
      .spread(function (company1, company2) {
        return Promise.all([
          User.register(_.merge(company1Owner, {company: company1})),
          User.register(_.merge(company1Employee1, {company: company1})),
          User.register(_.merge(company1Employee2, {company: company1})),
          User.register(_.merge(company1Employee3, {company: company1})),

          User.register(_.merge(company2Owner, {company: company2})),
          User.register(_.merge(company2Employee1, {company: company2})),
          User.register(_.merge(company2Employee2, {company: company2})),
          User.register(_.merge(company2Employee3, {company: company2})),
          User.register(_.merge(company2Employee4, {company: company2})),

          User.register(registered)
        ]);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.dir(err);
      })
      .done(function(){
        done();
      });
  });

});

after(function (done) {

  // here you can clear fixtures, etc.
  sails.lower(done);

});
```

Comment: NVM I got it. https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions/pull/114